# How to run john parallel on several CPU's?

Tags: password

If I use:

```
john --incremental UNSHADOWEDFILE
```

then I can see it uses only 1 CPU. How can I set john to use several CPU's for finding the weak passwords? (need to find weak ones faster because of an audit)

Comment: Trivially, split the file in four and run four separate instances.

Comment: @tripleee, it is not as trivial as you imply: ['Other approaches, such as splitting password files naively (without regard to salts), are typically less efficient'](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/FAQ.shtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to make sure that you use a recent John version that has OpenMP support enabled.

If you compile it yourself you have to explicitly enable OpenMP support in the makefile (and verify that needed dependencies are available - e.g. a GCC >= 4.2).

OpenMP support is not necessarily available for all hash methods, and the community edition (-jumbo) supports more than the official one.

With the resulting binary you can verify if it has OpenMP via calling `ldd` on it - it should display some mp-related libraries. Also you can specify via the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` the number of cores a OpenMP program should use - if it is unset the default (on Linux) should be: all cores.

See also the [notes on OpenMP in John's Wiki](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/parallelization#Built-in-parallelization-with-OpenMP).